# On-device debugging with Sony Ericsson Cedar (J108i)

Tags: debugging, java-me, sony

Unfortunately, I have to deal with J2ME (which I consider ancient technology these days) on Sony Ericsson J108i (aka Cedar).

Unfortunately I've failed to configure on-device debugging. I've done the following:

- enabled Java developer mode in service settings
- configured USB -> Advanced -> Internet access -> Via computer
- installed J2ME SDK 2.5.0.6
- disabled the Windows firewall
- tried the whole procedure on both Windows XP and Windows 7

Unfortunately, Connection Proxy fails to connect to the device. The network interface is there, named 'Sony Ericsson Device 1039 USB Ethernet Emulation (NDIS 5)', but when I try to connect, the following is logged:

```
[18.03.12 13:23:45] Getting device ip. Failed to get deviceip for interface(Sony Ericsson Device 1039 USB Ethernet Emulation (NDIS 5) - Sterownik miniport Harmonogramu pakietów). Trying to get it from Connection Proxy settings(sdkme.properties). java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to connect to the SEMC SDK Service1.
[18.03.12 13:23:45] Getting device ip. No device for interface=Sony Ericsson Device 1039 USB Ethernet Emulation (NDIS 5) - Sterownik miniport Harmonogramu pakietów
```

It actually looks like the interface is never assigned the correct IP. I've tried assigning IP manually, but it failed too (perhaps I did it incorrectly - the documentation is not really verbose here).

Any idea what I do wrong? Any success stories with on-device debugging using this particular phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get my Cedar device working on Vista 32-bit SP2:
 1. First of all, make sure you're not using jdk7uX (otherwise you have to install MSVC 10 redistributable pack to make SEMC_SDK_Service start properly).
 2. Edit SDK_Root/OnDeviceDebug/lib/sdkme.properties, set ipprovider.rebindOnConnect: true
(it's false by default), then uncomment and set proxy.device.ip: 192.168.8.2 and proxy.local.ip: 192.168.8.1 (both are commented out and empty by default)
 3. Run SDK_Root/OnDeviceDebug/bin/restart_service.cmd
 4. (Re)connect your Cedar device
 5. Wait about a minute
 6. Run SDK_Root/OnDeviceDebug/bin/restart_service.cmd
 7. Run arp -a in console and ensure your interface is using 192.168.8.*, this could also take about a minute
 8. Restart connection proxy and connect to your phone, everything should be OK
 9. You should repeat steps 4-8 after each Windows start

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I'll try to verify it asap (busy with Android these days).